# Poisson Distribution Problem.

Tags: probability-distributions

I have this problem that I think I've kind of solved but just wanted to make sure if it's correct.

The problem goes:

The homework submissions to the university computer center start at midnight (00:00). The number of homework submissions between midnight and any time t > 0 afterwords is distributed Poisson with mean λt, where λ > 0 is some constant. Let T be the time between midnight and the first submission. What is the distribution of T

I think the answer is: **exponential distribution**

because we have time that is continuous variable, and poisson is just for submissions that are between midnight that means that is for discrete variable

so the distribution of T needs to be exponential distribution.

Does that work?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct, but your explanation is not.

Problem with your explanation is, that you basically say, that $T$ has exponential distribution only because it is continuous. Since there are definitely more than one continuous distributions, how do we know, that $T$ does not have for example $\chi^2$ distribution (it is also continuous and positive)?

The right explanation is that $\{T_n\}$, where $T_n$ is time of n-th submission, is [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process) and times between occurrences of Poisson process, $T_n-T_{n-1}$, have [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). In your case $T=T_1-T_0=T_1$.

Answer (score 0):

You're given that
$$
    P(n)=\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}  e^{-\lambda t} 
$$

The time to the first homework submission is the same as the "end" of having zero homework submissions, so
$$
    P(0)=e^{-\lambda T} 
$$